# Why exception not the same when catching exception pointer?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm new to C++ exception handling. I tried to throw an exception pointer and caught it but it seems the later caught exception isn't the same as which I thrown.
Here's my code:

```
try {
    bad_exception e2 = bad_exception();
    cout << e2.what() << endl;
    cout << &e2 << endl;

    throw &e2;
}
catch (bad_exception* ex) {
    cout << ex << endl;
    cout << ex->what() << endl;
    cout << (*ex).what() << endl;
}
```

output:
bad exception
00CFFCF8
00CFFCF8
Unknown exception
Unknown exception

I'd expected the later will show the same name "bad exception". Can you explain this?

**updated:**
It seems the exception has the "auto delete" feature? I tried throwing a pointer to normal object (not inherited from exception). But I can still access the object and its properties in the catch block.

```
try {
    char str[5] = "eed8";
    A a = A();
    a.name1 = str;

    cout << a.show() << endl;
    cout << &a << endl;

    throw &a;
}
catch (A* exp) {
    cout << exp << endl;
    cout << exp->show() << endl;
    cout << exp->name1 << endl;
}
```

output:
eed8
007BF9DC
007BF9DC
eed8
eed8

Comment: All local stack variables will be destroyed as the exception unwinds the stack.  This includes `e2`!

Comment: @0x5453 thks. I created a local object but why I can still access it in catch block? see my updated.

Comment: Why are you trying to `throw` a pointer to a local variable? This strikes me as an unintentional error which may make this an X-Y problem. Exceptions should (ordinarily) be thrown by-value and caught by reference. Throwing a pointer, though possible, is non-idiomatic and confusing -- and can lead to scoping issues such as this example which is using a dangling pointer. If this is intentional, what exactly is it that you hope to accomplish with this pattern?

Comment: One  of the "joys" of undefined behaviour is that the observable effects can be consistent with whatever you consider to be "working", or you can see behaviour that you wouldn't expect (as you are).    In reality, your code is calling member functions on a dangling pointer (a pointer that once pointed at an object, but that object no longer exists).

Comment: Crashes on my machine.  Undefined behavior.  It's crazy.

Comment: I know the formal way is throw the exception value and catch the reference. I just wonder why can't catch the pointer cause I prefer using pointer. But now I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should throw exceptions by value (usually).

The problem here is you are throwing a pointer to an object. Unfortunately, by the time the pointer is caught, the object that it is pointing to has been destroyed, and thus you have an invalid pointer.

```
try {
    bad_exception e2 = bad_exception();
    cout << e2.what() << endl;
    cout << &e2 << endl;

    throw &e2;
}  // At this point the object "e2" goes out of scope
   // Thus its destructor is called.
   // So the pointer you threw now points at an invlalid object
   // Thus accessign the object via this pointer is UB.

catch (bad_exception* ex) {
    cout << ex << endl;
    cout << ex->what() << endl;
    cout << (*ex).what() << endl;
}
```

Rewrite it like this:

```
try {
    bad_exception e2 = bad_exception();
    cout << e2.what() << endl;
    cout << &e2 << endl;

    throw e2; // Throw a copy.
              // Throw an object that gets copied to a secure location
              // so that when you catch it is still valid.
}
catch (bad_exception const& ex) {  // catch and get a reference to the copy.
    cout << &ex << endl;
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

If you absolutely must throw a pointer, then use `new` to make sure the pointer has a dynamic life span (but remember, you will need to clean it up).

---

### Update:

> It seems the exception has the "auto delete" feature?

Not a thing.

> I tried throwing a pointer to normal object (not inherited from exception).

There is nothing special about the exception object (or any of its derived classes). It is simply a normal object. Like all objects (that are a class), the destructor of the object is run when the object reaches the end of its lifetime. If `A` does not have a destructor then the memory used by the object may not change (but it is not usable by other objects that are not your object).

> But I can still access the object and its properties in the catch block.

That is the bad side of "Undefined Behavior". I may look like it is working. It's not working, it just looks like it is. And it is just as likely to not work on some other situation.

Comment: thks. I updated my question

Comment: @irous Your update does not change anything. You are accessing an object after it has been destroyed. That object does not exist. What you are getting is called "Undefined Behavior" which means literally anything is allowed to happen as your program is invalid.

Comment: yeah. the object looks like being destroyed. I put a print statement in the destructor of A and it printed before logs in catch block.

Comment: Using operator `new` to create an exception is also problematic, because the act of creating the exception may also throw.   If that happens, instead of the exception you intend to throw (as a pointer) your code throws `std::bad_alloc` - which means the catch point receives information about how your program has failed to construct an exception, rather than about the error you (presumably) were seeking to report.